# why isn't my html required in input tag not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a fake log in page (anything which the user writes is considered and correct and therefore will be logged in) and the required bit of the code is not working on chrome.

I have tried putting the required bit in different places and it didn't work. I also tried to implement some javascript but did not succeed.

This code shows a form which asks for the username and password after sign in is hit, a JS function is triggered

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<div ng-app ng-init="checked = false">
    <form class="form-signin" name="form">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input class="form-styling"
               id="user"
               type="text"
               name="username"
               required />

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-styling"
               type="text"
               name="password"
               required />
        <div class="btn-animate">
            <a class="btn-signin" type="submit" onClick="sayHi()">Sign in</a>
        </div>
    </form>  
<div>
```

Javascript code which works with the html and will be triggered when the sign in button is hit.i am not sure how to implement javascript function insted of using a required tag

```
$(".btn-signin").click(function()
{
    $(".container").toggleClass("state_signed-in");
});

function sayHi()
{
    var txtName = document.getElementById("user");
    var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
    var name = txtName.value;

    txtOutput.value = "Hi there, " + name + "!"
} // end sayHi

if the input is left empty it shouldn't let the form to be submitted
```

Comment: I didn't understand by `fake log`

Comment: Is that an [tag:angularjs] related question?

Comment: @Sid anything which the user rights is correct and will trigger the javascript (no backend is to be coded ) my problem is that even when the user right nothing the js is still being triggered

Comment: According to html looks like angularjs not javascript.

Comment: remove `onClick="sayHi()"` from  `<a class="btn-signin" type="submit" onClick="sayHi()">Sign in</a>` and use event listener for submit

Comment: You are not even dealing with an actual form submission here. You have no submit button in your form - adding nonsense attributes like `type="submit"` on a _link_, which is not a form control to begin with, doesn’t change that. You are calling a JavaScript function here, no more, no less. The form validation mechanism has no reason to interfere here, because you don’t even get so far that an _actual_ form submission was attempted.

Comment: Go read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_forms_using_JavaScript

Comment: Note that the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error with the "Sign in" button probably and after 'required' you don't need the slash.

Try     `<input class="btn-signin" type="submit" onClick="sayHi()" value="Sign in">`

`<a class="btn-signin" type="submit" onClick="sayHi()">Sign in</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Need to pass form valuse from `ng-click="sayHi(form)"` HTML `ng-click` and check in controller 
 if form is valid or not if not then prevent the event.

```js
$scope.sayHi = function()
 {
    if (!$scope.form.$valid) 
    {
        $event.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-signin" type="submit" ng-click="sayHi(form)">Sign in</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" name="form">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input class="form-styling" id="user" type="text" name="username" required />
            <label>Password</label>
            <input class="form-styling" id="pass" type="text" name="password" required />
            <div class="btn-animate">
                <input class="btn-signin" type="submit" value="Sign in"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="txtOutput"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".btn-signin").click(function (e) {
                $(".container").toggleClass("state_signed-in");
                if($('#user').val().trim() !== '' && $('#pass').val().trim() !== '' ) {
                    sayHi();
                }
            });

            function sayHi() {
                event.preventDefault();
                var txtName = $('#user').val();
                if(txtName !== ''){
                    var html = "Hi there, " + txtName + "!"
                    $('#txtOutput').text(html);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form doesn't submit.

Your function fires on click.

You should be using `submit()`

```js
$(".form-signin").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  sayHi()
  $(".container").toggleClass("state_signed-in");
});


function sayHi() {
  var txtName = document.getElementById("user").value;
  var txtOutput = document.getElementById("txtOutput");
  txtOutput.value = "Hi there, " + txtName + "!"
} // end sayHi
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="checked = false">
  <form class="form-signin" name="form">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input class="form-styling" id="user" type="text" name="username" required />

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input class="form-styling" type="password" name="password" required />
    <div class="btn-animate">
      <button class="btn-signin" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <input id="txtOutput" disabled>
</div>
```

I have also changed few other details.

Answer (score -1):

Please check below code:
I have updated submit button to:
`<input class="btn-signin" onClick="sayHi()" value="Sign in" type="submit">`

Also your last div not closed, so now i closed this. `</div>`

```html
<div ng-app ng-init="checked = false">
    <form class="form-signin" name="form">
        <label  for="username" >Username</label>
        <input class="form-styling" id ="user" type="text" name="username" required>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input class="form-styling" type="text" name="password" required />
        <div class="btn-animate">
        <input class="btn-signin" onClick="sayHi()" value="Sign in" type="submit">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```